# casting or converting string value into date in postgres/jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to write a query that needs using the function `MAX()`. The data is stored in a `jsonb` column like: 
`{"created_at": "2012-08-03T02:32:44", "company": "apple"}`.

I would like to run the `MAX()` function on the 'created_at' key.

`SELECT MAX(data -> 'created_at) FROM ...` does not work.

`SELECT MAX(cast(data -> 'created_at) as DATE) FROM ...` does not work as well.

Comment: `->` just returns `json`. Did you try `->>` which returns `text`?

Comment: yeah i have just tried it suddenly and it worked. thnks anyway

Comment: ok apparently it does not work. I do not get an error, but the result is false. min() and max() returns always the same message

Comment: When casting to a `date` you are throwing away the time part. `max(cat(data ->>'created_at'  as timestamp))` should work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9025

Comment: Step through it. Make sure you are extracting what you want. Then make sure you are casting it correctly. Ensure you are passing into `max()` a date, timestamp, etc.

Comment: ok the answer i have posted is correct actually. I think i have a problem with group by.

Comment: i have another problem not what i have thought actualy and it is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645842/multiple-unwanted-records-in-group-by-clause-in-postgress

Answer (score 8):

you can use `date(colName ->> 'created_at')`

and you can use in WHERE conditions as well

```
date(colName ->> 'created_at') BETWEEN '2021-01-01' and '2022-01-01'
```

Answer (score 6):

I have randomly tried another attempt and it worked

`data ->> 'created_at' AS DATE` works since `->>` returns text

Comment: loved this one... you saved me.Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To convert it to a `Date` datatype, do this:

```
to_date(table.date_column->>'date', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_namespace
```

To a `Timestamp` datatype

```
to_timestamp(table.date_column->>'date', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.MS') AS timestamp_namespace
```

This will allow you to use BETWEEN dates syntax like so:

```
WHERE table.date_column ->> 'date' BETWEEN '2021-10-01' AND '2021-10-30'
```